# Слово "Бог": с прописной или со строчной

Tags: орфография

В классике русской литературы разных изданий встречается написание слова "бог" в сходном контексте как с прописной, так и со строчной буквы. Например,

> Во  главе  тамошнего  местного  духовенства  находился  тогда  епископ,
> человек,  надо  полагать, очень  добрый,  участливый  и  чистосердечный.  Он
> принимал скорбь народа близко  к своему  сердцу и сам усердно молился, чтобы
> Бог послал дождь на землю, но дождя все-таки не было.

*Н.С.Лесков. Повесть о богоугодном дровоколе.*

> Говорят:
>
> — Мы еще и сами не знаем, что учиним, а только будем на бога надеяться, и авось слово царское ради нас в постыждении не будет.
>
> Так и Платов умом виляет, и туляки тоже.

*Н.С.Лесков. Левша. Сказ о тульском косом Левше и о стальной блохе.*

Есть ли формальное правило, строго определяющее, когда надо писать со строчной, а когда с прописной. Или выбор может быть оставлен за автором (издателем)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В советских изданиях "бог" всегда писался со строчной буквы, потому что "бога нет".

В дореволюционных изданиях и пост-советских (современных) изданиях "Бог" пишется с заглавной буквы (если имеется в виду христианство, где Бог един и любые упоминания Бога относятся к Нему), причем и местоимения, относящиеся к Нему (Его, Ему, Он и т. п.) (т.е. слово "Бог" здесь выступает в роли имени).

Если же божество относится к пантеону языческих божеств (греческих, египетских и т.п.) то у этих божеств есть собственные имена (Анубис, Гефест, Кецалькоатль), поэтому "бог" здесь не играет роль имени собственного и пишется с маленькой буквы.

Думаю что и в современной практике отдельные издательства могут придерживаться советских норм (например в какой-нибудь газете с названием "Голос атеиста").

**UPDATE**: Вот цитата из книги *Мильчин, Чельцова. Справочник издателя и автора, 2003*:

> 3.22.1. Имена богов, апостолов, пророков, святых
>   С прописной буквы пишутся слово Бог (в значении единого верховного существа) и имена богов во всех религиях. Напр.: Иегова, Саваоф, Яхве, Иисус Христос…
>
> Примечание 2. Слово бог в значении одного из множества богов или в переносном значении пишется со строчной буквы. Напр.: бог Аполлон, бог войны, боги Олимпа.
>
> 3.22.2. Устойчивые сочетания со словами бог, господь
>   В многочисленных устойчивых сочетаниях, постоянно употребляющихся в разговорной речи вне прямой связи с религией, следует писать бог (а также господь) со строчной буквы. К ним относятся: (не) бог весть или (не) бог знает (кто, что, какой) — о ком-, чем-либо не очень важном, значительном; бог (господь) его знает — неизвестно, не знаю; бог с ним (ней, тобой, вами), (не) дай бог, ради бога, убей меня бог, как бог на душу положит, не приведи бог (господь), богом обиженный, забытый богом, к богу в рай, не верить ни в бога ни в черта, не гони бога в лес, коли в избу влез, и др.
>
> Не следует также писать с прописной буквы междометия ей-богу, боже, боже мой, господи, господи боже мой, бог ты мой, боже упаси, боже сохрани, в отличие от тех случаев, когда формы боже, господи выражают обращение к Богу.
>
> В некоторых случаях выбор написания зависит от контекста. Так, может быть написано слава Богу (если контекст указывает, что говорящий действительно благодарит Господа Бога) и слава богу (если по контексту ясно, что употреблен расхожий разговорный оборот: В тот раз он, слава богу, пришел вовремя!
>
> Но в сочетании не слава богу прописная буква невозможна (У него все не слава богу)».

Взято с сайта http://www.gramota.ru/forum/klass/109512/

Comment: У христианского бога тоже есть имя собственное (Иегова).

Comment: @Anixx Да, но смысл в том что когда христианин говорит "Бог" никакого другого бога он не имеет в виду.

Comment: при чем тогда наличие имени собственного?

Comment: @Anixx При том что древний грек может сказать "бог" но это лишь указание на какого-то бога, как слово "река" лишь указание на одну из многих рек. Т.е. чтобы обратиться к богу этот человек должен назвать его по имени. А в христианстве все слова относящиеся к богу эквивалентны его имени и поэтому пишутся с заглавной буквы.

Comment: @Anixx Христианство же разное, Иегова - это у свидетелей Иеговых, а у православных христиан и католиков Бог Отец, Бог Сын, Бог Святой Дух (Святая Троица). Обычно православные христиане подразумевают одного конкретного своего "Бога", которого называют еще Господом. Имена всегда разные, это зависит от первоначального перевода Заветов. В некоторых религиях (буддизм, кришнаизм), верующие зовут своего бога по имени.

Comment: @Clever Masha А православные христиане в курсе? Википедия: Иего́ва (Его́ва) — традиционная транскрипция имени Бога в русских переводах Ветхого Завета.

Comment: @Anixx Боюсь что обсуждение скатывается в оффтопик.

Comment: @Clever Masha - Господи, прости! Будда же не бог, весь буддизм построен на том, как выйти из-под власти Бога. И "кришнаизма" никакого не бывает, те, кого вы называете "кришнаитами", поклоняются Господу Вишну, они называются вайшнавами.

Comment: По-моему, это один из примеров "авторской" орфографии. Правила русского языка, как хорошо показано в цитате из Мильчина, найденной Artemix-ом, допускают написание с большой буквы в определенном классе случаев. В каждом конкретном случае, однако, автор решает сам. Если это верующий человек, и он пишет о едином боге, то он будет писать с большой буквы. То есть большая или маленькая буква зависит от объема уважения, вкладываемого в это слово. Это похоже на написание вы/Вы.

Comment: @farfareast В некотором смысле "авторская орфография" в печатных изданиях [это миф](http://www.gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_4_punct/). Как только текст попадает к издателю - все зависит от политики издательства.

Answer (score 8):

В советской литературе слово "бог" писалось с маленькой не потому, что "бога нет", а потому что христианский бог Яхве (Иегова) рассматривался точно так же, как и все другие боги, и ничем от них не отличался. То есть, конкретно христианский Яхве рассматривался не как некое верховное божество, а лишь как один из множества богов.

По этой же причине любой, кто не исповедует какую-либо ветвь христианства, и не обязан писать "бог" с большой буквы, поскольку для любого представителя иной религии Яхве - лишь один из многих (чужих, ложных, вымышленных).

Таким образом, способ написания данного слова зависит лишь от собственного отношения говорящего к конкретному божеству: поклоняется он ему или нет.

p.s. Если кто-то полагает, что Зевс является не только верховным, но и единым божеством (т.е. признаёт его самого, но отрицает его пантеон), то вполне себе может писать Бог Зевс - это вполне соответствует правилам :)

Comment: Сейчас все обязаны писать с большой буквы, даже атеисты.

Comment: Anixx, это вам так только кажется. "бог". И ничего, и гром с небес не поразил, и инквизиторы запаздывають...